# Disabling the behaviour of CSS Height:auto and Width:auto for a specific class

Tags: html, css, tinymce

I'm utilising [TinyMCEv4](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/) for a solution which has the built in image toolbar plugin.

When a user resizes an image within the WYSWYG editor, the HTML for the image is updated accordingly via the image width/height attributes on the image element:

```
<img src="img.jpg" alt="Image" width="300" height="200">
```

If the user were to resize the image by doubling the size of it within the WYSYWG editor of TinyMce, the html would is updated to:

```
<img src="img.jpg" alt="Image" width="600" height="400">
```

The problem is - I've got some CSS which prevents the width and height attributes from working. The following CSS is applied to all images sitewide, for responsive purposes:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Is there a way to reverse these CSS rules so that the  width/height attributes work for images within a specific class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer for the not-too-distant future.

**Cascade Layers** are coming. Because the presentational hints that are obtained from the HTML attributes are considered as belonging to a cascade precedence below author layers, we can use `revert-layer` to undo the assigned setting here.

You can already do this in Firefox. Chromium and Safari should have implementations shortly, if not already.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
img[height] {
  height: revert-layer;
}
img[width] {
  width: revert-layer;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="Image" width="300" height="200">
```

In general, you would use `revert-layer` in the same layer as the settings you needed to revert. Here, all our CSS is in the "unlayered" layer.